# TabFragments FragmentPageAdapter Parcelable Bundle

Tags: android, xamarin, tabs, fragment, parcelable

I'm developing a Xamarin Android application, I've got a main activity and a Tab Fragment that holds four fragments. From the MainActivity I sent a parcelable object to the Tab Fragment, through arguments (which as I said holds the 4 fragments).
The thing is I that this object needs to be sent to the fragment 1, this fragment sent the object to the Fragment 2 and so on. Each one of these fragments needs to change some different properties of the same object. It's like a wizard form, where each tab is a step.
How can I approach that? How can I send the object from fragment to the next fragment?

I hope I made it clear. 
Thanks in advance.

Here are some lines of code:

```
//In the MainActivity
private void ListItemClicked(int position)
{
 //this way we don't load twice, but you might want to modify this a bit.
   if (position == oldPosition)
      return;

  oldPosition = position;

 Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
 switch (position)
 {
    case 0:
    fragment = FragmentHome.NewInstance();
    break;
    case 1:
    sheet = new Hoja();
    bundle = new Bundle();
    pa = Parcel.Obtain();
    bundle.PutParcelable("sheet", sheet);
    pa.WriteBundle(bundle);
    pa.SetDataPosition(0);                    
    fragment = TabFragment.NewInstance();
    fragment.Arguments = bundle;
    break;
 }            

 SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
   .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
   .Commit();
}

//In the TabFragments class receive the object
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup     container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   //var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

   parcelable_sheet = (Hoja)Arguments.GetParcelable(PARCEL_KEY);
}
```